# Eloquent WhereHas With Several Nested Wheres from Array

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a database with tables: questions, answers, responses, and respondents. Questions have answers, which have responses, which are owned by a respondent (Respondents can have many responses).

I'm trying to make correlations by zeroing in on all the responses to questions related through respondents who chose a certain answer to a question. So, what else did people who answered that they were 18 - 20, answer.

The trick is I want to do this across multiple respondents and multiple answers.  For example, what else did people who are 18 - 20, and like the color green like:

I currently have this working in an "or" fashion where each additional answer_id  I add pulls in respondents who chose either one of the two answers:

```
$cFilters = array() of answer_ids;
$respondents = Auth::user()->account->respondents()
                ->whereHas('responses', function($q) use($cFilters) {
                    $q->whereIn('responses.answer_id', $cFilters);
                })->get();
```

I'd ultimately like to have them working in an "and" fashion where adding in another answer_id shows only respondents who have chosen both answers identified  by the answer_ids, can't quite figure that one out.  Here is what I've tried so far that doesn't raise errors, but also doesn't seem to work correctly:

```
$cFilters = array() of answer_ids;
$respondents = Auth::user()->account->respondents()
                ->whereHas('responses', function($q) use($cFilters) {
                    foreach($cFilters as $answer_id) {
                        $q->where('responses.answer_id', $answer_id);   
                    }
                })->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had to resort to raw SQL, but it works:

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM respondents 
                WHERE id IN ( ';  

        $i = 1;
        foreach($cFilters as $answer_id) {
            $query = $query . 'SELECT respondent_id FROM responses WHERE answer_id=' . $answer_id;
            if($i < count($cFilters)) {
                $query = $query . ') AND id IN (';
            } 
            $i++;
        }
        $query = $query . ')';

        $respondents = DB::select( DB::raw($query) );
```